# GPS working on iOS 4 but not on iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios

In my AppDelegate I have a property:

```
GPSTracking*        _GPSTracker;
```

Which is responsible for starting location updates. It uses singleton `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and uses it like this:

```
@implementation GPSTracking

-(id) initWithDelegate:(MSpyAppDelegate *) _del
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {   
        self.mainDelegate = _del;
        [[InternalGPSManager sharedInstance] setMainDelegate: self.mainDelegate];
    }
    return self;
}

//Start getting locations
- (void)startUpdatingByManager
{
    [[InternalGPSManager sharedInstance] startLocationUpdateInSeparateThread];
    self.gpsTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(gpsUpdateInterval * 60)    target:self selector:@selector(startUpdatingByManager) userInfo:nil repeats:NO] 
}
```

Actual location manager delegate:

InternalGPSManager.h:

```
@interface InternalGPSManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
   {
      CLLocationManager *locationManager;
   }
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

InternalGPSManager.m

```
static InternalGPSManager *sharedCLDelegate = nil;
@implementation InternalGPSManager
@synthesize locationManager;


- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) 
    {
        self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    }

    return self;
}
    - (void)startLocationUpdateInSeparateThread
    {
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startLocationUpdate) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    }
    - (void)startLocationUpdate
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        [pool release];
    }
```

It works on iOS 4, but not on iOS 5. Location delegate callbacks never get called.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Humor me, and try changing your code to this:

```
- (void)startLocationUpdateInSeparateThread
{
   // Not a separate thread!
   NSLog(@"Starting updates using delegate: %@", self.locationManager.delegate);
   [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

PS: why aren't you using ARC???

Comment: ARC works with iOS 4.0+. No reason not to use it at this point. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: It will take you only a few minutes to run the test, then report back.

Comment: Thanks, I was testing different solutions. Still no luck. I guess I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're starting location updates in a background thread, that is then cleaned up as soon as you tell the location updates to start.

[From the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsthread_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on `detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:`:

> The objects aTarget and anArgument are retained during the execution
>   of the detached thread, then released. The detached thread is exited
>   (using the exit class method) as soon as aTarget has completed
>   executing the aSelector method.

So, as soon as your `startLocationUpdate` completes, that thread is cleaned up.

Then, from [these other Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124) on the location manager delegate:

> The methods of your delegate object are called from the thread in
>   which you started the corresponding location services. That thread
>   must itself have an active run loop, like the one found in your
>   application’s main thread

So, the `CLLocationManager` wants to call you back with location updates on the same thread that you started them on (thread that called `startUpdatingLocation`), but that thread may be gone by the time a location fix is available.  I can also believe that you *could* get lucky with the code on one device/OS, and not on another.

So, either:

- Start the location updates on the main thread.  Starting location updates is an asynchronous operation, so just because you do that on the main (UI) thread, doesn't mean the whole UI is blocked until a location fix is available.  It just means that when location is available, you'll be called back on the UI thread.

Or ...

- Make your background thread hang around for as long as you want to keep receiving location updates

To do the first, just do this

```objc
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

instead of calling `startLocationUpdateInSeparateThread`.  To do the second, add this code:

```objc
- (void)startLocationUpdate 
{ 
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; 

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];  // keep this background thread from being cleaned up

    [pool release]; 
}
```

If your `CLLocationManagerDelegate` callback (for receiving location updates) doesn't do any heavy processing, then I'd recommend just avoiding the background thread altogether.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! I tried removing thread creation, but delegate callbacks aren't triggered. I also tried the second option, but still no luck. The key point is that the original solution worked on iOS 4. I guess I just miss something...

Comment: @Mighter, well, with any **dangling** such-and-such problem, you **can** sometimes get lucky that something doesn't get cleaned up as soon as it possibly could.  It doesn't shock me that an OS version change might break this, but it looked wrong to me from the start.  Anyway, if you've modified the code and it still doesn't work, I'd need to see what your code looks like now to help.  If it's slightly different, I'd just post an "Update:" at the bottom of your question.  If it's a lot different, I'd open a new question.  Good luck!